# Should I avoid executing the same function declaration multiple times for performance reasons?

Tags: javascript, performance, closures, higher-order-functions

A powerful feature of Javascript is how you can use closures and higher order functions to hide private data:

```
function outerFunction(closureArgument) {
    var closureVariable = something;
    return function innerFunction() {
        // do something with the closed variables
    }
}
```

However, this means that every time I call `outerFunction`, a *new* `innerFunction` is declared and returned, which means that `outerFunction(arg) !== outerFunction(arg)`. I wonder to what extent, if any, this might impact performance. As an example, a typical alternative would be to create a constructor that holds the data, and put `innerFunction` on the `prototype`:

```
function Constructor(argument) {
    this.argument = argument;
    this.variable = something;
}

Constructor.prototype.method = function() {
    // do something with this.argument and this.variable
}
```

In that case, there is a single function that is shared by a number of instances, e.g `new Constructor().method === new Constructor().method`, but the data can not easily be made private, and the function can only be called as a method, so it has access to its context variables (This is just an example; there are other ways to solve the issue; my question is *not* actually about constructors and prototypes).

Does this matter from a performance perspective? It seems to me that since a function is always a literal, and the function body itself is immutable, Javascript engines should be able to optimize the above code example so that there shouldn't be a big performance impact because we have "multiple" functions instead of a single, shared function.

**In summary:** Does running the same function declaration multiple times come with any significant performance penalty, or do Javascript engines optimize it?

Comment: That's an *extremely* common idiom in JavaScript, and especially in popular JavaScript frameworks, so it's a good bet that runtimes are heavily optimized for it. Understand that the function body only needs to be interpreted once; thereafter the creation of a new function object is very inexpensive.

Comment: Agreed with @Pointy. The two should get optimized to roughly the same thing.

Comment: The way to answer performance questions is benchmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, engines do optimise closures. A lot. There is no *significant* performance or memory penalty.

However, the prototype approach still *can* be faster, because engines are better at detecting the potential to inline a method call. You will want to step through the details in [this article](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html) - though it could easily be outdated by newer compiler optimisations.
But **don't fear closures** because of that, any differences will be negligible for most cases you encounter. If in doubt, and with real need for speed, benchmark your code (and avoid premature optimisation till then). If closures make your code easier to read, write, maintain, go for them. They are a powerful tool that you don't want to miss.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and references. I also found the following article - http://neversaw.us/2013/09/04/on-the-performance-of-closures-in-v8/ The tl;dr is that closures *can* have a rather bad performance effect, but don't have to. I.e, it's tricky.